# What is the best way to get UID from user within Chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using "user" resource to define the user within Chef.
Now, I want to retrieve the value of `UID` and `GID` for the same user.

Can this be done using the ruby code within chef?

Right now, I am trying to use bash resource and running the following command:

```
id -u $USERNAME
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the automatic attributes contributed by [Ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html).

That information is accessible via

```
# uid
node['etc']['passwd']['$USERNAME']['uid']
# gid
node['etc']['passwd']['$USERNAME']['gid']
```

From the command line, you can explore the attributes as follows:

```
$ ohai etc/passwd/vagrant
{
  "dir": "/home/vagrant",
  "gid": 900,
  "uid": 900,
  "shell": "/bin/bash",
  "gecos": "vagrant,,,"
}

$ ohai etc/passwd/vagrant/uid
900
```

If you create a user during the chef run and want to access its information within the same chef run, you probably have to trigger a [reload](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ohai.html) of the responsible *ohai* plugin. (It might be possible that triggers this automatically, but I wouldn't expect so.)

```
ohai 'reload passwd' do
  plugin 'passwd'
  action :reload
end

user 'john' do
  notifies :reload, 'ohai[reload passwd]', :immediately
end
```

As of Chef 15, [the etc plugin is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57953198/24108)

Answer (score 4):

For this you can use Ruby's `Etc` class: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html#method-c-getpwnam

```
[15] pry(main)> Etc.getpwnam('david').uid
=> 501
[16] pry(main)> Etc.getpwnam('david').gid
=> 20
```