# How to enable Ohai Plugin to produce ['etc']['passwd']?

Tags: chef-infra

I have upgraded my Chef Client from `14.0` to `15.3.14` but issue rose whenever I execute chef-client on my node(macOS Mojave).
The client output is:

```
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/macos/recipes/mac_init.rb:62:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/macos/recipes/mac_init.rb:

 55:    action :create
 56:    owner 'administrator'
 57:    group 'localaccounts'
 58:    mode  '0775'
 59:  end
 60:
 61:  # Template for bash history
 62>>   node['etc']['passwd'].each do |user, data|
 63:
 64:    template "/Users/#{user}/.bash_profile" do
 65:      source '/default/bash_profile.erb'
 66:      owner 'administrator'
 67:      group 'staff'
 68:      ignore_failure true
 69:    end
 70:  end
```

It seems that `node['etc']['passwd']` is no longer readable which result to have a value of `nil`.
I've checked another machine that was newly bootstrapped and verify it on Chef Server UI but the result is, there was no 'etc' in the attributes tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

reading the [release notes of ohai](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#optional-ohai-plugins) it says:

> ## Optional Ohai Plugins
>
> Ohai now includes the ability to mark plugins as optional, which skips those plugins by default. This allows us to ship additional plugins, which some users may find useful, but not all users would want being written to their Chef server. The change introduces two new configuration options; `run_all_plugins` which runs everything including optional plugins, and `optional_plugins` which allows you to run plugins marked as optional.
>
> By default we will now be marking the `lspci`, `sessions` and `passwd` plugins as optional. Passwd has been particularly problematic for nodes attached LDAP or AD where it attempts to write the entire directory to the node. If you previously disabled this plugin via Ohai config, you no longer need to. Hurray!

but you can always [enable back the optional plugins](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html#enabling-optional-plugins):

> ## Enabling Optional Plugins
>
> Optional plugins can be enabled in the `client.rb` configuration file:
>   `ohai.optional_plugins = [
>     :Sessions,
>     :Lspci
>   ]`

in your specific case:

```rb
ohai.optional_plugins = [
  :Passwd
]
```

assuming you installed ohai using bundler, then you can check that the `passwd` is there by executing

```
$ bundle exec ohai etc
```

## configuration

to have such behavor constantly, then:

- if [chef-zero](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#about-chef-zero) is used when invoking `chef-client`,  [`client.rb`](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb.html) can be used, which can be stored in a repository.
- use [`ohai` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ohai.html). something like:

  ```rb
  ohai 'reload_passwd' do
    action :reload
    plugin 'etc'
  end
  ```
- contribute to [chef-client cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client), to have complimentary support for `node['ohai']['disabled_plugins']`

**UPDATE:**
support for this has been introduced into chef-client cookbook:

> - `node['ohai']['disabled_plugins']` - An array of ohai plugins to disable, empty by default, and must be an array if specified. Ohai 6 plugins should be specified as a string (ie. "dmi"). Ohai 7+ plugins should be specified as a symbol within quotation marks (ie. ":Passwd").
> - `node['ohai']['optional_plugins']` - An array of optional ohai plugins to enable, empty by default, and must be an array if specified. Ohai 6 plugins should be specified as a string (ie. "dmi"). Ohai 7+ plugins should be specified as a symbol within quotation marks (ie. ":Passwd").

Comment: A very well-explained answer. I couldn't thank you enough for answering my question.

Comment: If you have spare time, I also wanted to ask how to apply this config in an efficient way on multiple nodes.

Comment: Oh while digging some threads and docs, I've seen that ohai resource used for reloading plugins. But unfortunately, it seems that the plugin is still disabled. I'll file a feature request maybe on chef-client cookbook repo for enabled plugins.

Comment: Here's the request I've sent to Chef-client regarding this matter and answered it smoothly https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client/issues/636#event-2799877773

Comment: @GilroyToledano: amazing!