# How do i access node['etc']['passwd']?

Tags: chef-infra, ohai-gem

I'm trying to use the `ohai` resource to make `node['etc']['passwd']` available. My recipe looks like this:

```
ohai 'reload etc plugin' do
  plugin 'etc'
  action :reload
end

log "Was etc plugin reloaded? #{node.key?('etc')}"
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57953198/1707427) this should work. But:

```
  * log[Was etc plugin reloaded? false] action write
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

This is with

```
Chef Infra Client: 17.0.242
Ohai: 17.0.42
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable Ohai Plugin to produce \['etc'\]\['passwd'\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952305/how-to-enable-ohai-plugin-to-produce-etcpasswd)

Comment: @Dog9w23 I've even linked to the answer from that question and demonstrated that it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following is noted on [Reload Ohai after a new user is created](https://docs.chef.io/resources/ohai/#examples) in chef examples

```rb
ohai 'reload_passwd' do
  plugin 'etc'
end
```

and as you probably know, ohai does not load by the default](chef release notes) the [`Passwd` plugin](https://docs.chef.io/ohai/#optional-plugins).

combining both with the [ohai resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/ohai/#syntax), and since the first snippet did not work for you, maybe the following will do the trick

```rb
ohai 'reload_passwd' do
  plugin 'passwd'
end
```

**UPDATE:** it seems that the version you specified had many issues. i suggest you  will update chef version.

Comment: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
----------------------------------
Property plugin must be one of: String!  You passed :Passwd.


After changing :Passwd to 'passwd':


ERROR: Encountered error while running plugins: #<Ohai::Exceptions::AttributeNotFound: No such attribute: 'passwd'>

Comment: @Sören: i've update the answer with you fix, thanks. also, updating  chef version solved many issues.